# How to provide add-to-page functionality for custom role user

Tags: liferay

My requirement is that I have a student user and student role . I have mapped this user with student role. Admin will provide few portlets for student role.So, when he gets sign in to the portal he could able to add / decorate whatever the portlets he can access. I want to provide the add to page functionality with limited access. I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start off by reading the Liferay User Guide, in particular the section that can be found here:

http://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/managing-users-user-groups-organizations-sites-teams-and-roles

This isn't really a programming question, and would probably be better suited being asked over at [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/search?q=Liferay) unless you're trying to do this in code.